# Parsing WordPress RSS Feed with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

I am using JQuery to read and parse a self-hosted WordPress atom feed. Here's an example of the XML generated by WordPress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"
  xml:lang="en-US"
  xml:base="http://example.com/wp/wp-atom.php"
   >
    <title type="text">Feed Title</title>
    <subtitle type="text">Feed Subtitle</subtitle>
    <updated>2013-04-19T21:33:48Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/wp" />
    <id>http://example.com/wp/index.php/feed/atom/</id>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://example.com/wp/index.php/feed?feed=atom&#038;cat=10" />
    <generator uri="http://wordpress.org/" version="3.5.1">WordPress</generator>
    <entry>
        <author>
        <name>Author Name</name>
        </author>
        <title type="html">Article Title</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/wp/index.php/2013/04/19/article-title/" />
        <id>http://example.com/wp/?p=1418</id>
        <updated>2013-04-19T21:33:48Z</updated>
        <published>2013-04-19T21:33:16Z</published>
        <category scheme="http://example.com/wp" term="firstcategory" />
        <category scheme="http://example.com/wp" term="secondcategory" />
        <category scheme="http://example.com/wp" term="thirdcategory" />
        <summary type="html">A summary excerpt of the article [...]</summary>
        <content type="html" xml:base="http://example.com/wp/index.php/2013/04/19/tons-vs-tonnes/">A summary excerpt of the article with a whole bunch more text taht is not in the summary.
        </content>
        <link rel="replies" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/wp/index.php/2013/04/19/article-title/#comments" thr:count="0"/>
        <link rel="replies" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://example.com/wp/index.php/2013/04/19/article-title/feed/atom/" thr:count="0"/>
        <thr:total>0</thr:total>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Here's my JQuery ajax code to consume this feed and display it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//example.com/wp/index.php/feed?feed=atom&cat=10",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var $xml = $(data),
            items = [];

        $xml.find("entry").each(function(i) {
            if (i === 30) return false;
            var $this = $(this);
            console.log($this);

            items.push('<div><h3>' + $this.find("title").text() + '</h3><p><small>Published by ' + $this.find("author").text().trim() + ' on ' + publisheddate.toDateString() + ' ' + publisheddate.toTimeString() + '</small></h3>' + $this.find("content").text() + '</div><hr />');
        });
        $("#displayDiv").html(items.join(''));
```

This is working!!
I want to enhance this with a list of all the category tags for this entry as follows:

```
firstcategory | secondcategory | thirdcategory
```

If you look at the XML, you will notice there are three category elements in the sample entry.

I've tried several methods and have failed miserably. I've reverted to working code from which I have extracted the above sample javascript, so I don't have my failed attempts left to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you use `publisheddate.toTimeString()` which gives an error.

To get your catgeories use something like:

```
            var categories = ""; 
            $this.find("category").each(function(j) {
                categories += " " + ($(this).attr("term"));
            })  
            items.push("categories:" + categories);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. I must've been close, because your code seems familiar. Somehow it just wasn't working though....